# How to prevent all radio buttons from being highlighted in a rating system

Tags: html, css

I am creating a star rating system with 2 areas to rate(2 rows of stars). When I select a rating in the first row of stars, it works correctly. However, when I select in the second row, no matter what rating I select, all five stars are highlighted. Can anyone assist me with where I went wrong with the CSS?

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.stars {
  background: url("stars.png") repeat-x 0 0;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.stars1 {
  background: url("stars1.png") repeat-x 0 0;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.stars input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.stars1 input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.stars input[type="radio"].star-5:checked~#span1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.stars1 input[type="radio"].stars-5:checked~#span2 {
  width: 100%;
}

.stars input[type="radio"].star-4:checked~#span1 {
  width: 80%;
}

.stars1 input[type="radio"].stars-4:checked~#span2 {
  width: 100%;
}

.stars input[type="radio"].star-3:checked~#span1 {
  width: 60%;
}

.stars1 input[type="radio"].stars-3:checked~#span2 {
  width: 100%;
}

.stars input[type="radio"].star-2:checked~#span1 {
  width: 40%;
}

.stars1 input[type="radio"].stars-2:checked~#span2 {
  width: 100%;
}

.stars input[type="radio"].star-1:checked~#span1 {
  width: 20%;
}

.stars1 input[type="radio"].stars-1:checked~#span2 {
  width: 100%;
}

.stars label {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  text-indent: -999em;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  background: transparent !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.stars1 label {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  text-indent: -999em;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  background: transparent !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.stars label:hover~#span1 {
  background-position: 0 -30px;
}

.stars1 label:hover~#span2 {
  background-position: 0 -30px;
}

.stars label.star-5:hover~#span1 {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.stars1 label.stars-5:hover~#span2 {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.stars label.star-4:hover~#span1 {
  width: 80% !important;
}

.stars1 label.stars-4:hover~#span2 {
  width: 80% !important;
}

.stars label.star-3:hover~#span1 {
  width: 60% !important;
}

.stars1 label.stars-3:hover~#span2 {
  width: 60% !important;
}

.stars label.star-2:hover~#span1 {
  width: 40% !important;
}

.stars1 label.stars-2:hover~#span2 {
  width: 40% !important;
}

.stars label.star-1:hover~#span1 {
  width: 20% !important;
}

.stars1 label.stars-1:hover~#span2 {
  width: 20% !important;
}

.stars #span1 {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background: url("stars.png") repeat-x 0 -60px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-width 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-width 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-width 0.5s;
  -o-transition: -o-width 0.5s;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.stars1 #span2 {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background: url("stars1.png") repeat-x 0 -60px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-width 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-width 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-width 0.5s;
  -o-transition: -o-width 0.5s;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="stars">
  <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-1" id="star-1" />
  <label class="star-1" for="star-1">1</label>

  <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-2" id="star-2" />
  <label class="star-2" for="star-2">2</label>

  <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-3" id="star-3" />
  <label class="star-3" for="star-3">3</label>

  <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-4" id="star-4" />
  <label class="star-4" for="star-4">4</label>

  <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-5" id="star-5" />
  <label class="star-5" for="star-5">5</label>

  <span id="span1"></span>
</div>
<br>

<div class="stars1">
  <input type="radio" name="star1" class="stars-1" id="stars-1" />
  <label class="stars-1" for="stars-1">1</label>

  <input type="radio" name="star1" class="stars-2" id="stars-2" />
  <label class="stars-2" for="stars-2">2</label>

  <input type="radio" name="star1" class="stars-3" id="stars-3" />
  <label class="stars-3" for="stars-3">3</label>

  <input type="radio" name="star1" class="stars-4" id="stars-4" />
  <label class="stars-4" for="stars-4">4</label>

  <input type="radio" name="star1" class="stars-5" id="stars-5" />
  <label class="stars-5" for="stars-5">5</label>

  <span id="span2"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I am a new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all the stars1 selectors, you forgot to give different width for the #span2 and all of them are set to 100% width. Edit those in your css

```
.stars1 input[type="radio"].stars-5:checked ~ #span2 {
    width: 100%;
}
.stars1 input[type="radio"].stars-4:checked ~ #span2 {
    width: 80%;
}
.stars1 input[type="radio"].stars-3:checked ~ #span2 {
    width: 60%;
}
.stars1 input[type="radio"].stars-2:checked ~ #span2 {
    width: 40%;
}
.stars1 input[type="radio"].stars-1:checked ~ #span2 {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: @kish77 Happens. If you have any other queries, dm me(after you get enough reputations). I still remember how silly was my first question(you can check it). XD All the best!